# Download build results in pipeline

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I build java-program with Maven in pipeline job. After successful build I can get acsess to builded jar in Jenkins's home directory, which corresponds to this job. How can I do opportunity to downoload this jar file to user?

Thank you for your attention!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download artifact possible with:
`archiveArtifacts artifacts: 'target/*.jar'`
And now you can download this artifact from job's results.
Here is example from Jenkins's [documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/examples/#archive-build-output-artifacts).

Answer (score 0):

The conventional way to do this is to provide your own repository manager such as [Sonatype Nexus](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjRw_Tx0Z7TAhVDO7wKHU0CCH8QFggbMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sonatype.org%2Fnexus%2F&usg=AFQjCNFVmBL3RfVkUsQLea5VMi8oI6N6Vw&sig2=UE1rGbx3SIa8KzAKYgRkDg) or [JFrog Artifactory](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjzt4SD0p7TAhXHybwKHVrAD2oQFggbMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.jfrog.com%2Fartifactory%2F&usg=AFQjCNHP8Frc2Q8TZ7s03oEZ0WpCsGr4JQ&sig2=VTBNEsYpwRqpNqvxZdyYLA).

With proper pom configuration:

```
 <distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>releases</id>
        <url>http://your.repo/release/repository</url>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>snapshots</id>
        <url>http://your.repo/snapshot/repository</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
```

your pipeline can run `mvn clean deploy` instead of `mvn clean install` or whatever you're using now.

In addition you would typically configure your repo manager to act as a mirror for maven central (and perhaps others).

Developers then configure this repository manager in their local ~/.m2/settings.xml file so that their builds automatically download all their artifacts from there.

Any other downstream process can also download artifacts from the repo manager via HTTP.

Comment: Thank you for your attention! I incorrectly explained to you what I mean